# Сборка и запуск приложения на C# без IDE

Tags: c#

Как собрать и запустить приложение (скрипт) на C# на машине без IDE, при наличии только .NET Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на машине установлен .NET Framework, то в папке сборок должен быть компилятор командной строки `csc.exe`. Например, для версии 3.5 это папка `%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5`.

Написание файла (hello.cs):

```
using System;

namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Привет!");
        }
    }
}
```

Компиляция и сборка файла:

```
> "%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe" hello.cs
```

Исполнение файла:

```
> hello.exe
```